# How to access static properties of an object that is itself a property of another object?

Tags: php, object, static-members

In PHP, is it possible to access the static properties of an object that is itself a property of another object, using similar syntax below:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public $bar;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    const TEST = 123;
    function __construct() {}
}

$bar = new Bar();
$foo = new Foo();

echo Bar::TEST; // ok
echo $bar::TEST; // ok
echo $foo->bar::TEST; // error
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the property to a variable.

```
$foo = new Foo();
$bar = $foo->bar;
echo $bar::TEST; // that's good.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) instead of inheritance on that property. So it would be something like this (changed to an example from the above PHP manual page):

```
<?php
class A
{
  public static function who() 
  {
    echo __CLASS__;
  }
  public static function test() 
  {
    static ::who();
     // Here comes Late Static Bindings

  }
}

class B extends A
{
  public static function who() 
  {
    echo __CLASS__;
  }
}

B::test();
?>
```

Here's another thread that might be relevant or helpful: [PHP Inheritance and Static Methods and Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298359/php-inheritance-and-static-methods-and-properties)

Comment: Awesome resource Federico. I'll debug my code since it's borked.

Comment: @JakeB. That code, copied and pasted, produces the error: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'TEST'`

Comment: @reformed changed my example. Shows me for posting untested code.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the effort. This solution seems to introduce additional, unnecessary logic. @Federico's answer shows how to accomplish the static reference very simply.

Comment: Yeah, assigning a class instance to a variable is almost always easier to manage in the long run. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

more tricky, but you can use **ReflectionClass**

```
echo (new ReflectionClass(get_class($foo->bar)))->getconstant("TEST");
```